# refreshTable No delay on first time

Tags: javascript

I am creating a automatic refreshing code in JavaScript, it currently refreshes every second, however their is a delay when you first load the page. How would I make no delay?

**JavaScript**

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            refreshTable();
        });

        var firsttime = function refreshTable() {
            setInterval(function() {
                $.get('artist.php', function(data) {
                    $("#artistname").html(data);
                }, 'text');
                $.get('title.php', function(data) {
                    $("#songname").html(data);
                }, 'text');
                $.get('presenter.php', function(data) {
                    $("#presentername").html(data);
                }, 'text');
                $.get('listeners.php', function(data) {
                    $("#listeners").html(data);
                }, 'text');
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        refreshTable();
        refreshTableAuto();
    });

    function refreshTableAuto() {
        setInterval(refreshTable, 1000);
    }

    function refreshTable() {
            $.get('artist.php', function(data) {
                $("#artistname").html(data);
            }, 'text');
            $.get('title.php', function(data) {
                $("#songname").html(data);
            }, 'text');
            $.get('presenter.php', function(data) {
                $("#presentername").html(data);
            }, 'text');
            $.get('listeners.php', function(data) {
                $("#listeners").html(data);
            }, 'text');
        }
```

Comment: This only loads it initially, but it does not automatically refresh.